# How to obtain the username and password from the URI with NodeJS HTTP2 module?

Tags: node.js, http2

When receiving a request with the form https://username:password@example.com using nodejs [http2 module](https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html), how can I access the username and password?

Specifically, when responding to an `on('stream')` event?

The provided headers object did not contain any pseudo headers with the user-info, and I could not find a mention for it in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be pretty straight forward:

```js
// server.js
const http2 = require('node:http2');
const server = http2.createServer();
server.on('stream', (stream, headers) => {
  console.log(headers['authorization']);
  stream.respond({
    ':status': 200,
  });
  stream.write('Hello World!');
  stream.end();
});

server.listen(8080);
```

Test it with:

```bash
curl --http2-prior-knowledge http://user:pass@localhost:8080
```

or use this snippet as node client:

```js
// client.js
const http2 = require('http2')

const session = http2.connect('http://localhost:8080')

const req = session.request({
  ':path': '/',
  authorization: 'Basic dXNlcjpwYXNz',
})
req.end()

req.setEncoding('utf8')
let data = ''
req.on('data', (chunk) => {
  data += chunk
})

req.on('end', () => {
  console.log(data)
  session.close()
})
```

You then have to split `headers['authorization']` and base64 decode the second part.

If this header is empty: Do you have any reverse proxy between your client and node?

Comment: Testing with curl doesn't work for me. I test with the nodejs client, the header is `undefined`. I don't have any proxies, I'm testing on localhost

Comment: I've updated my answer to contain a sample node client.